# Timeout with GWT

Tags: gwt, proxy

I received a new computer at work today and for some reason all of my GWT programs are timing out when I try to build them in eclipse.

Specifically I am seeing this message:

INFO: Unable to access http://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java&release=1.3.5&timestamp=1277158890&api_versions=['1.0']
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

I tried to build just the basic sample project and it does the same thing. I am behind a proxy, but I have set up all the correct information in eclipse (i think). I don't understand what else it could be though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually ended up being a jar file that was not included in my classpath for some reason. Like I said I was building these projects from scratch again so I must have forgot that one. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Right click your GAE project, Debug As>Debug Configurations...
2. In the dialog window, select (x)= Arguments tab
3. In the VM Arguments part, add in the end 
   `-Dhttp.proxyHost=<your proxy server> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<Proxy port>`

try to debug application, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a firewall issue - check that your firewall allows java to connect to the network, or that the proxy settings are correct.

Comment: I am sure I have all of my proxy settings set up correctly for my machine. I have also configured java to work with a proxy. Just to make sure i am putting in the command line switch in my runtime configuration on eclipse: ie) -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyserver.com  -Dhttp.proxyPort=80. Still no go...

Comment: Step 1: Install tcpdump or equivalent. Step 2: Verify that your browser can connect there, and that tcpdump shows the actual packets moving. Step 3: use tcpdump to check wether actual packets are produces by java.